# How to normalize each tensor in a batch separately without in place operations?

Tags: python, pytorch, normalization

I have a series of images where each pixel should be in the range [0, 1]. I want to know I am running a deep learning model on these images and I want to know how to normalize each image in the batch in such a way that the images will always be in the range[0, 1] after the transformation.

This is what I am trying to do

```py
for idx in range(x.shape[0]):
    x[idx] = x[idx] - x[idx].min()
    x[idx] = x[idx] / x[idx].max()
```

However this leaves me with this error:

```
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [2, 128, 128]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 10; expected version 9 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

What is the solution to this?

Some other things to consider: I can't use batch normalization because each image in the batch must be normalized separately. I can't use layer normalization because this is a convolutional network and I don't know the image size ahead of time. I cannot use instance normalization because I have multiple channels and the relative size between channels is important.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can avoid the in place operations by defining a new tensor as follows

```py
mins = torch.zeros((x.shape[0], *(1,)*len(x.shape[1:])))
maxs = torch.zeros((x.shape[0], *(1,)*len(x.shape[1:])))
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    mins[i] = x[i].min()
    maxs[i] = x[i].max()
x = (x - mins) / (maxs - mins)
```